# I have a problem with building AOSP 13 from official source code and got CTS test errors

Tags: android, android-source, ninja, cts

I am building AOSP 13 on an x64 laptop with 16 GB ram and 12th generation core i7 spec. After successfully syncing my repo with the `repo sync` command, I just executed the following standard commands. At the beginning of the build process, I got the following errors. By looking at the Internet resources, everybody talked about a synchronization problem. However, my synchronization process was finished successfully without any errors or warnings.

```
root@User:/home/user/android13# source build/envsetup.sh
root@User:/home/user/android13# lunch 47
root@User:/home/user/android13# m
16:10:32 ************************************************************
16:10:32 You are building on a machine with 15.3GB of RAM
16:10:32 
16:10:32 The minimum required amount of free memory is around 16GB,
16:10:32 and even with that, some configurations may not work.
16:10:32 
16:10:32 If you run into segfaults or other errors, try reducing your
16:10:32 -j value.
16:10:32 ************************************************************
16:10:32 Build sandboxing disabled due to nsjail error.
build/make/core/soong_config.mk:209: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIR has
 been deprecated. Use SYSTEM_EXT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.
build/make/core/soong_config.mk:210: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIR ha
s been deprecated. Use SYSTEM_EXT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=13
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_x86_64
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=x86_64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=x86
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-6.2.0-34-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-22.04.3-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=TQ3C.230805.001.B2
OUT_DIR=out
PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=device/generic/goldfish device/generic/goldfish-opengl 
hardware/google/camera hardware/google/camera/devices/EmulatedCamera
============================================
[  1% 3/195] test github.com/google/blueprint/pathtools
FAILED: out/host/linux-x86/bin/go/blueprint-pathtools/test/test.passed
out/host/linux-x86/bin/gotestrunner -p build/blueprint/pathtools -f out/host/lin
ux-x86/bin/go/blueprint-pathtools/test/test.passed -- out/host/linux-x86/bin/go/
blueprint-pathtools/test/test -test.short
--- FAIL: TestGlobEscapes (0.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestGlobEscapes/**/* (0.00s)
        glob_test.go:571: incorrect matches list:
        glob_test.go:571:  pattern: "**/*"
        glob_test.go:571:      got: []string{"a/", "b", "a/a"}
        glob_test.go:571: expected: []string{"*", "**/", "?", "a/", "b", "**/*",
 "**/a", "**/b/", "**/b/b", "a/a"}
        glob_test.go:571: incorrect deps list:
        glob_test.go:571:  pattern: "**/*"
        glob_test.go:571:      got: []string{".", "a"}
        glob_test.go:571: expected: []string{".", "**", "**/b", "a"}
    --- FAIL: TestGlobEscapes/**/\* (0.00s)
        glob_test.go:571: incorrect matches list:
        glob_test.go:571:  pattern: "**/\\*"
        glob_test.go:571:      got: []string(nil)
        glob_test.go:571: expected: []string{"*", "**/*"}
        glob_test.go:571: incorrect deps list:
        glob_test.go:571:  pattern: "**/\\*"
        glob_test.go:571:      got: []string{".", "a"}
        glob_test.go:571: expected: []string{".", "**", "**/b", "a"}
    --- FAIL: TestGlobEscapes/\*\*/* (0.00s)
        glob_test.go:571: incorrect matches list:
        glob_test.go:571:  pattern: "\\*\\*/*"
        glob_test.go:571:      got: []string(nil)
        glob_test.go:571: expected: []string{"**/*", "**/a", "**/b/"}
        glob_test.go:571: incorrect deps list:
        glob_test.go:571:  pattern: "\\*\\*/*"
        glob_test.go:571:      got: []string{"."}
        glob_test.go:571: expected: []string{".", "**"}
    --- FAIL: TestGlobEscapes/\*\*/**/* (0.00s)
        glob_test.go:571: incorrect matches list:
        glob_test.go:571:  pattern: "\\*\\*/**/*"
        glob_test.go:571:      got: []string(nil)
        glob_test.go:571: expected: []string{"**/*", "**/a", "**/b/", "**/b/b"}
        glob_test.go:571: incorrect deps list:
        glob_test.go:571:  pattern: "\\*\\*/**/*"
        glob_test.go:571:      got: []string{"."}
        glob_test.go:571: expected: []string{".", "**", "**/b"}
FAIL
16:10:32 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (1 seconds) ####
```

I executed `repo sync` and `m clean` commands several time. But the problem still persists. Can anyone help me how I can handle the situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with physically copying the source code of AOSP from an Ubuntu PC to a external hard drive with NTFS file system. I had copied the entire AOSP source code without compression. So, a few files those placed in test directories were affected by the NTFS file system limitations. When I copied them to my Ubuntu PC, the problem exposed. This is why `repo sync` and `m clean` could not solve the problem.

To solve the problem, I physically deleted the CTS and test folders from the source code, and again, executed the `repo sync` command. After replacing those deleted folders with new ones from the origin, the build process was done without any serious problem.

Comment: Yes, a case sensitive file system like EXT4 is really preferred! In my case, back in the days of Android P (9), even repo sync would not succeed in an NTFS disk on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @RajatGupta. At my first try, I thought the problem is because of repo synchronization issue.